# Typescript autocomplete for return type of function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a simply function what would return value of object by key and, if it is a function, it would execute it and return correct type, so it can be autocompleted by code editor.

```
type defaults = {
  a: "A" | "B" | (() => "A" | "B");
  b: "X" | "Y" | (() => "X" | "Y");
};

const myOpts: defaults = {
  a: () => "A",
  b: () => "X",
};

function option(name: string) {
  if (!myOpts[name]) {
    return null;
  }

  return typeof myOpts[name] === "function"
    ? myOpts[name].call()
    : myOpts[name];
}

console.log(myOpts.a);      // Autocomplete works
console.log(option("a"));   // Autocomplete does not work at all
console.log(option("xyz")); // Should warn that it does not exist!!!
```

So, is it possible to tell that the return type of the function is the type of value that is found by key in some object.

Comment: Shouldn't the name argument for the option function be a `keyof defaults` instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm assuming you just want to have auto completion for anything that can be deduced from the type, in that case, you could just use the [keyof operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)

In your scenario, you would change the `option` function to:

```
function option(name: keyof defaults): 'A' |'B' | 'X' | 'Y' | null {
  const prop = myOpts[name];
  if (!prop) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof prop === 'function') {
    return prop();
  }
  return prop;
}
```

Which would give you a warning, if you try to use an unknown key as an argument.

Now the last change that was needed, was to change how the potential function would be called. You could use `prop.call( null )` here as well, but why not directly call it instead (if you are anyhow sure it's a function as checked before)

You can try it in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAJhBmBDArgG2AZygXigbwCgopEAuKAIgEEKoAfSgIVoYApWBKHAPkpvqYUOAbiJQARuQoANFpQCac9l2y8ZciopEEAvqIIBjAPYA7DMCgBbEAHkwmcnCRpMOfGLJROPPhQA0YpJeKmqyAXoEBPDIJgbAAJamUEb2iSasJoiWEOQA1hAgRvCwCCjoGBzkAORUVfRVjHUMVdJNUFXybSZoqO7ExmYWYABOKW7WdpgA2pnZALqixPHFrACEIylchMTEwxDAyMMmUN2oqItQOpFLK6CQRVAbYDjYuFXRsQmmVVtiu-uHY5PTgXK7-A5HR6jMD6K6GUwYIyoCAAOlQRgA5qwJvYMCjECIdjsAPTEqBUZDAIzGSxgZHAaAAdyMw1yGHhZiRqPRWJSX3SFEQQkJxFJ5Mp1KMtPp0BgRggWBMRgszNZJAsiDOHMRyLRmNYfLSrAoAA8QAAvYXCKBigDKAAsjGgYFBGYhIcB7YgLPELHKFSdlVAICb4uZVhGCEA)

As a remark, based on the type inference, the current function wouldn't actually `return null;` anywhere now (it will always be any of the non-nullable properties) but I added the null function result to not have to change to much of your code :)

Another option of changing your code would be to use some more generic option, say:

```
function option<T>( source: T, name: keyof T): any {
  const prop = source[name];
  if (!prop) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof prop === 'function') {
    return prop();
  }
  return prop;
}
```

which would still give you validation, but the result type will probably need to be any at that time, or string if you always intend to return string values from it

Comment: Thanks, but I do now know the values for `'A' |'B' | 'X' | 'Y' | null` <- these can be anything depending on the input data

Comment: Hm, why not use a generic so the return type is also dependent on the parameter? You'll get pesky errors when you try to return, but casting it is fine. You could also try overloads but they *do* get pretty long if the `defaults` object is large.

Comment: @Andrew I've just added the things based on your sample code, I would agree with cats that using `option<T>( source: T, value: keyof T)` would make a more generic approach possible

Comment: OK, but is it possible to get rid of `: any`? I would like to have return type depending of the type of `myOpts[name]` to have autocomplete and to have a type check.

Comment: The answer is actually not the one I was looking for, but I marked it as accepted anyway, because it maybe helps someone else.